# How to capture errors from ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to run a raw SQL query as following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(some_query);
```

Can I capture any errors that happen while executing the query? If yes, how?
Does `execute` returns anything? It doesn't say in the documentation.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rescue errors as normal.  For example:

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(some_query)
rescue
  # do stuff with exception
end
```

Have a look at the [MySql (for example) adapter's code](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9bcf01b23c25e640da7908ac8b1b49fbf7d2e51a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb#L318) to see what's going on.

In this case, `execute` returns a `MySql::Result` object.

Answer (score 4):

`execute` method is typically implemented by respective database adapters and returns Result object from respective database libraries. So, if you are using Mysql the return value will be of type `Mysql::Result`.

Typically, if there is an error, the method will simply raise an exception which can be rescued.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. Execute statement returns the error that it receives from the database and that can be captured in a variable and displayed.

Comment: Can you post an example?